# how to solve a multiple choice quiz with actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

i have created a multiple choice question .it hav 3 options in a custom made dropdown menu.whenever click count is 2 in this dropdownmenu should display correct answer in actionscript 2.

```
var click_count:Number=0;
drop_1_btn.onPress = function()
{
    click_count = click_count + 1;
    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 1;
    trace(click_count);
};

drop_2_btn.onPress = function()
{
    click_count = click_count + 1;
    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 2;
    trace(click_count);
};

drop_3_btn.onPress = function()
{
    click_count = click_count + 1;
    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 3;

    trace(click_count);
};
```

Comment: Sooo....what should the correct answer be exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have created a textbox named `click_cnt` and put its `alpha` is to 0..

```
drop_1_btn.onPress = function()
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 1;
    drop4_text.text = "1 million";

    var count:Number = parseInt(click_cnt.text);
    count = count + 1;
    click_cnt.text = count;
    if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) == 2)
    {
        _root.tick4.gotoAndStop(4);
        drop4_text.text = "3 million";
    }
    else
    {
        if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) == 1)
        {
            _root.tick4.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        else
        {
            if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) > 2)
            {
                drop4_text.text = "3 million";
            }
        }
    }
};

drop_2_btn.onPress = function()
{
    drop4_text.text = "2 million";

    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 2;
    var count:Number = parseInt(click_cnt.text);
    count = count + 1;
    click_cnt.text = count;
    if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) == 2)
    {
        _root.tick4.gotoAndStop(4);
        drop4_text.text = "3 million";
    }
    else
    {
        if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) == 1)
        {
            _root.tick4.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
        else
        {
            if (parseInt(click_cnt.text) > 2)
            {
                drop4_text.text = "3 million";
            }
        }
    }

};

drop_3_btn.onPress = function()
{
    gotoAndStop(1);
    an = 2;
    _root.tick4.gotoAndStop(2);
    drop4_text.text = "3 million";

};
```